# Run Adobe Fireworks commands from Command Line

Tags: flash, command-line, fireworks

I've written few Fireworks commands (jsfw files) and Flash commands that I use for my image processing. Is it possible to run them from the command line without launching the whole UI app for Fireworks or Flash?

Answer (score 0):

I know [Keith Peters](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/) had a chapter in [Extending Flash MX 2004](http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=1590593049) about calling jsfl scripts from the command line, but it will open up Flash, as in the whole UI. I don't see how you can do that without opening the UI.

If you want to do some image processing from the command line I suggest giving [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php) a try.

Goodluck,
George

Answer (score 0):

The JSFL API can't be accessed outside the IDE-s, so you must run Flash or Fireworks in order to be able to run the commands.

Cheers,
Rob